# Free tool to convert Flash to GIF?

Tags: flash

Is there a free tool that allows me to **convert a Flash entity** (like a Flash ad) into an **animated GIF** image?

Comment: Yeah, I want it animated, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Given the same caveat as Frank there are (apparently) several 3rd party tools that can do this.

SWF Glanda

[Squidoo](http://www.squidoo.com/swf-to-gif)

Aunsoft SWF Converter

[Media Convert](http://media-convert.com)

[Source](http://www.webmaster-talk.com/graphics-forum/159672-how-convert-flash-swf-animated-gif.html) - word of warning though. That's an old (2008) thread so the products mentioned might not be available any more. However, it might give you a starting point for further searches.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Adobe Flash CS 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Creative_Suite#Creative_Suite_5) to save an [FLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWF#Related_file_formats_and_extensions) file as an image.
It's free for a trial.

Comment: Does it convert flash to animated gif?

Comment: I dont recall.  Got to be careful with animated gifs, they can become huge, and gifs never look as great as a png or jpeg because of their color limits.  I think adobes tool for animated gifs is Fireworks, although i create them in photoshop with the animation panel.  Your best bet for online animation is using some javascript and jquery animate.